# JavaScript runtime error: 'RefreshImageVerifier' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a image verifier in oUpWizStep2 update panel of wizard steps 2.  I wan to refresh the image through Page_PreRender but i get JavaScript runtime error: 'RefreshImageVerifier' is undefined. It works fine in others page without wizard steps.

my code below

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 1 Then
        Dim oUp As UpdatePanel = TryCast(Wizard1.FindControl("oUpWizStep2"), UpdatePanel)
        Dim imgVerifier As ImageVerifier = CType(Wizard1.FindControl("ImgVerifierS2"), ImageVerifier)
        ' ## Refresh the verification code on call back.
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(oUpWizStep2, oUpWizStep2.GetType, "scriptname", "RefreshImageVerifier('" & imgVerifier.ClientID & "','ImageVerifier.axd?uid=" & imgVerifier.MyUniqueID & "');", True)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you define RefreshImageVerifier ?

Comment: It defined in a class. Somehow, could not find ImgVerifierS2 in html page source. Only step 1 controls shows in page source